# Accessibility: how does a blind person (currently) navigate, read text, and play video on the Android app

Tags: support, android-app, accessibility

How can a blind person play a video from Stack Exchange, such as one from Music Theory & Practice.

Comment: You can't. Use the full site for this.

Comment: Do I need to use Chrome with NDVA for this? What would I use at the moment, if I wanted to test the accessibility of the SE site for blind users (that did not want to resort to being helped by relatives or friends to read the SE posts)?

Comment: What do I need to install on my Android device, or on Windows, to accomplish the described navigation feat with a web browser?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. All I know is that the app does not have any special features for this kind of navigation. If you mean this as general question about accessibility in android apps, not about the specific Stack Exchange app, then the question is off topic here.